# Partial fraction decomposition algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, partial-fractions

So I was faced by this problem: If $p,q \in K[x]$, with $q = q_{0}^{\alpha_{0}} \dots  q_{m}^{\alpha_{m}}$, all of $q_{i}$ irreducible and $\alpha_{i}$ natural numbers. So, there is some $p_{0} \dots p_{m} \in K[x]$ where
$$
\frac{p}{q}=\sum_{j = 0}^{m}\frac{p_{j}}{q_{j}^{\alpha_{j}}}.
$$

---

So, at first sight, it looks a lot like the partial fractions decomposition, which we use a lot in Calculus, but I can't prove this. Any help, I will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've found a text that explain this. You may click [here](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2012/29-32-2012/cookIMF29-32-2012.pdf). And look for propositions $3.5$ and $3.6$.